# .Net Core [FromBody] JArray to ICollection

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

Apologies first; I'm a recent mover from PHP to .Net Core MVC:

I'm using Model binding in a controller method and can't get one of the properties bound to a C# Class. If I use `ICollection<> or IList<Attendee> AttendeeList` the whole "param" is null. If using ´dynamic AttendeeList´ for the data type, I do receive the params object, where AttendeeList is a ´dynamic {Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JArray}´, e.g.

```
AttendeeList {[
  "f650c4f8-b8df-44ef-b6a8-866de50af211",
  "10400a5c-3281-4edb-8103-b571d2265ebd"
]}
```

Method Header:

```
public async Task<JsonResult> Batch([FromBody] ScheduleEditParameters param)  {
```

ScheduleEditParameters is simple:

```
public class ScheduleEditParameters
{
    public string Key { get; set; }
    public string Action { get; set; }
    public ScheduleData Value { get; set; }
}
```

ScheduleData is this (abbreviated):

```
public class ScheduleData
{
    [Key]
    [Required]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Subject { get; set; }
    public bool AllDay { get; set; }
    public DateTime StartTime { get; set; }
    public dynamic AttendeeList { get; set; } // works, request contains dynamic Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JArray
    //public ICollection<Attendee> AttendeeList { get; set; } // does not work
}
```

Attendee looks like this:

```
public class Attendee
{
    [Key]
    public int ScheduleDataId { get; set; }
    [Key]
    public  Guid AttendeeId { get; set; }
}
```

I'm not quite certain where my error is. The JArray appears to be transmitted properly when using dynamic, so I assumed .Net could convert this into a List or Collection?
The question is stupid, I'm certain, but I got stuck here...

Comment: In your example AttendeeList is an array of Guid's not an array of Attendee objects. That's why it works with the dynamic.

Comment: Thanks @R.Rusev - what would I need to do to change that? The transmitted Strings are actually Guids, and I'd like to insert them into the Table "Attendees" with that particular ScheduleDataId. I thought by using the ForeignKey that part would be populated automatically, but I'm probably wrong.

Comment: Simply change the `public dynamic AttendeeList` to `public ICollection<Guid> AttendeeList`

Comment: Thanks again. This does work, however I can't store it this way. Based on your comments, I shall rephrase my question, but I guess I better take a short break first, my head is swimming.