# Entity Framework Core: Persisting One-To-Many without existing foreign Entity

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

Having recently moved to C#/.Net Core from other languages, I got stuck on a problem with EF Core that I couldn't figure out from the documentation and hope you may be able to help. In a way this is related but not identical to my previous question [.Net Core [FromBody] JArray to ICollection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54023813/net-core-frombody-jarray-to-icollection)

My database holds a number of appointments that are rendered on a Syncfusion schedule. Attendees can be invited to these appointments. To facilitate that, a list of users is displayed in the editor and a JSON array of guids is transmitted with any insert or update action.

The User entity itself is not available within the scope of the application, so I'd like to persist only their Guids for each appointment. I had foreseen this structure:

Appointments (Start, End, ..., ´ICollection Attendees´)
Attendee would simply consist of AppointmentsId and Guid - 
Since any one Guid can only attend each Appointment once, a composite Key made up of these two attributes appeared to be useful.

Any appointment can have none, one or many associated Guids.

In Code, I have this (abbreviated):

```
public class Appointment
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public DateTime StartTime { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Attendee> AttendeeList { get; set; } 
    [NotMapped]
    public List<Guid> PostedAttendeeList { get; set; } // Contains a list of Guids after an Insert/Update POST action from [FromBody]
}
```

Attendee would simply be made up of the Appointment Id and a Guid of a user.

```
public class Attendee
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }         
    public int AppointmentId { get; set; }
}
```

Attendee's configuration is this:

```
public class AttendeeConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<Attendee>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Attendee> builder)
    {
        builder.HasKey(x => new { x.Id, x.AppointmentId });
    }
}
```

After receiving a POST from the schedule, ´PostedAttendeeList´ may be empty or contain one or more Guids.
If it is an existing Appointment, ´AttendeeList´ may be empty or contain one or more Guids.
I'm wondering about a few things:
a) is there a better way to go about persisting this kind of data? I've tried to understand Owned Entity Types but failed to see if that would help me here.
b) if this is indeed an ok way to handle this, how can I make sure that ´AttendeeList´ is identical to ´PostedAttendeeList´ after processing, so that all new entries are added and those not present in ´PostedAttendeeList´ are removed through EF Core?

I'm especially confused about whom's responsibility it is to maintain ´AppointmentId´ - I wanted to keep the property visible but I understand that EF would fill that in when operating within the base property? Ie. that within the class ´Appointment´, a ´AttendeeList.Add(new Attendee() { Id = "1234-abcd-..." }´  would automagically fill in the AppointmentId upon saving?

If you read until here and are confused, please take a moment to remember when you started programming - I'm thoroughly confused and unable to come up with a better question. Even if you cannot help out with an answer, maybe you could help me make the question better. Thank you all very much! Any comment with suggestions will result in an update to my question in order to improve it.